# How to update global variable that contains another variable that updates in a function

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I insert the content of a variable in a function to the end of  a global variable.

So basically link this
 `"link21 = '<div class="gohome"></div>' + back;"` But I need the back variable to update in this global variable if clicked.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
   back = 'declaring';
   link21 = '<div class="gohome"></div>' + back;  /// This is a global variable
   link22 = '<div class="start"></div>' + back;  /// This is the global variable

   $(document).on('click', '.inter [class]', function () {
   id = 'test';     
   back = '<div id="' + id + '"></div>';  /// this is the function variable

   });
```

At the end of this function the link21 global variable should equal

`"<div class="gohome"></div><div id="test"></div>"`

and the link22 global variable to

`"<div class="start"></div><div id="test"></div>"`

But they end up looking like `"<div class="gohome"></div>declaring"`.

Please note the below things:

There is a lot more link variables. link23, link24. Etc. So basically I need to insert the back variables content to the end of quite a few variables.

Comment: Where is `declaring` in your expected results?

Comment: Any time you have to do the same thing to "quite a few variables", you probably should be using an array rather than separate variables. The fact that the variables are all the same except for a number makes this even more appropriate, i.e. they should be `link[23]` rather than `link23`

Comment: So what you are saying is that you have littered your code with a shitload of globals? What could possibly go wrong!

Comment: @Barmar How would I implement an array for this? (I am a newbie to JQ)

Comment: Nothing to do with jQuery, it's just ordinary Javascript arrays, similar to most other programming languages. `var link = ['<div class="gohome"></div>', '<div class="start"></div>', etc...]`. You can then use a `for` loop or jQuery's `$.each()` function to iterate over the array elements if you need to do the same thing to all of them.

Comment: Does the index start at 0 or 1?

Comment: It starts at 0, like most languages.

Comment: maybe you should read a language textbook, these questions are extremely basic.

Comment: Plan too. So with this line: $('.inter').html(window[className]);  how would I change the className variable to an arrray? Would it be: $('.inter').html(window[link[className]]); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the problem is you've already initialized `link21` and `link22` *before* your `click` event happens.  Changing the value of `back` is not going to affect those two variables.  In your `click` handler, you'll need to update each one again.  Something like:

```
   link21 = '<div class="gohome"></div>';
   link22 = '<div class="start"></div>';

   $(document).on('click', '.inter [class]', function () {
      var id = 'test';     
      var back = '<div id="' + id + '"></div>';  /// this is the function variable

      link21 += back; // Append local back variable to the end
      link22 += back;

   });
```

Comment: I love you. THAT IS PERFECT. Now instead of appending each variable seperately is there a way I could use "className = this.className;" to apply that apending what ever variable I am using?